# Can we use identityserver4 in an api build in dotnetframework?

Tags: c#-4.0, identityserver4, .net-framework-version

Using this as token generator for our different api's. we will use identityserver4 to protect our api built from dotnetframework not the .netcore

Comment: Refer to  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/750

Comment: The question is not clear enough: do you mean you have IdSrv4 (ASP.NET Core anyway) + MVC5/WebAPI 2.0 (.Net 4.x)?

Comment: @d_f hi yes. By the way already solved it using the identityserver3.accessvalidationtoken it can be viewed here. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1908

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting Web API 2.2 with IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41024075/protecting-web-api-2-2-with-identityserver4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.It can be solved using identityserver3.accesstoken
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1908